# How can i update a cordova lib for my app (2.1.0 to 5.1.1)

Tags: java, android, cordova

How can i update a cordova lib for my Android Application from Version 2.1.0 to 5.1.1 i can't download the .jar file from the offical webpage

Comment: forget about the jar, install the latest version from npm, create a new project, move your www code to the new project www and add the plugins you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**using bellow command**s

```
npm install -g cordova
```

using this command latest version are installed this command fire in to your CMD

**And if you want to down your cordova version 5.0 to 3.6.3 or any other cordova version then use bellow command**

```
npm install -g cordova@3.6.3-0.2.13
```